# Android HTTP requests

Tags: java, http

I'm trying to use an HTTP GET request to accomplish the tasks of an HTTP POST request. I realize that this doesn't make sense and is poor practice, but is this possible? I want to be able to execute an HTTP GET that contains the URL along with a list of NameValuePairs. The NameValuePairs should **not** be included in the URL. On the server side (PHP), it should identify that the request is a GET and then proceed to perform the proper actions that correspond to the keys of the NameValuePairs.

My motivation for doing this is to be able to mask the type of HTTP request. In other words, if everything is a GET request, anyone monitoring network traffic wont be able to draw useful information from the request types.

I guess it's also worth noting that this is for research purposes.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. By violating the RFC in insane ways: Attach a message body to the GET request like you would do with a POST request.

> My motivation for doing this is to be able to mask the type of HTTP request. In other words, if everything is a GET request, anyone monitoring network traffic wont be able to draw useful information from the request types.

That is a poor reason. Just use https.

> I guess it's also worth noting that this is for research purposes.

Doesn't make it any better.

Comment: https isn't an option for this situation. We're trying to highlight flaws in academic research for network-level android malware detection systems in the realm of http.

Comment: Oh? Hm. Here's an idea: You could disguise your key/value pairs by placing them in prepared cookie headers. It shouldn't be too hard to obfuscate them in a way that they will look much like regular session cookies.